# How to keep range selection in navigator in Highchart highstock when changing navigator series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linechart

I have an chart with navigator like this

[image]

When i change navigator series by this code, it did not keep range selector, it get full range

[image]

```
chart.navigator.baseSeries.forEach(series => {
                let navigatorSeries = series.navigatorSeries;

                if (series.name == this.navigatorTagName) {
                    if (!navigatorSeries.visible) {

                        navigatorSeries.setVisible(true);
                        series.setVisible(true);
                    }

                    navigatorSeries.update({
                        lineColor: series.color,
                    }, false);

                    if (series.zones.length > 0)
                        navigatorSeries.update({
                            zoneAxis: 'x',
                            zones: series.zones
                        });

                    navigatorSeries.setData(series.userOptions.data, false, false, false);
                } else {
                    navigatorSeries.setData(null, false, false, false);
                }
            });

            chart.redraw();
```

[image]
How can I keep range selected before change navigator series? Thanks

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with the sample data? You can start from this basic template: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w9hznsey/

Comment: thank for your feedback, I use zoom function and can handle my case.